# TFS: How to add more 'CheckIn' actions

Tags: tfs

Out-of-the-box TFS provides ability to either "Associate" or "Resolve" bug/task during check-in action.

I've added additional state "Implemented", created transition from "Active" to "Implemented", added into its "Action" value "Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" and expect to have "Implemented" option in the list of "Check-in Action" on the "Pending changed => Work Items" panel.

I've saved updated work item type, imported it into TFS, 'refresged' team explorer... but in "Check-in Action" list there are still only "Associate" and "Resolve".

Please advise: how to add additional options into that list and implement switch of work item state.

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The checkin actions aren't item workflow states, but are used to trigger the transition of a work item from one state to another.

As a starting point, have a look at [the MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194975.aspx) to get a better idea of what's required.

You might also want to look at [this older thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/332aa080-9c1d-422d-856f-e67ae78b7c71) on the support forums.

Comment: The first link is no longer available, but this topic sounds similar to the one discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194970(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've found is that the only "resolve" action is allowed for Check-in operation. And it is only available if from "current" state you have defined "Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" action. Some time it work's, sometime now. If you are adding few actions from one state (with different name) - they both works,... but not exactly as I want... don't know why...